# Optimising memcopy inside OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, memcpy

I am using OpenCL kernel, solely to copy one array to another(a part of a project), using custom memcpy function :

```
void myMemCpy(__global void *dest,__global void *src, size_t n) {
   __global char *csrc = (__global char *)src; 
   __global char *cdest = (__global char *)dest; 
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        cdest[i] = csrc[i]; 
}
```

I am using OpenCL SVM feature with OpenCL version 2.1.

Is there any way to optimize the copying routine or any other way to do copy inside the kernel ?

Answer (score 0):

I think putting an [`clEnqueueCopyBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueCopyBuffer.html) into the command queue on the host side would be the best option.

In your OpenCL function, each work-item does the whole copy, which doesn't make sense unless your ND-Range only has a single workitem. It's similar to starting the same `memcpy()` in multiple threads in a non-OpenCL program.

You would have to use at least `get_global_id()` inside your kernel split the work among the workitems inside your ND-Range. Depending on your ND-Range and your actual device, different memory access patterns might be better suited for the hardware. The hardware vendor's OpenCL optimisation guide is a good starting point here.